# Laravel 7: Why when I'm logged I can access route for reset password?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I realized can access to reset password route even when I'm logged. I want to can access only if user is logout.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the default Laravel Auth routes (Auth::routes() in web routes file). In there, the reset password routes are protected behind the `web` middleware only. You can check the route list alongwith their middleware using the command: `php artisan route:list`.

What you have to do here is to add `guest` middleware to those reset password routes. For Laravel 7, it can be done by following code:

```
Auth::routes()
Route::middleware('guest')
    ->group(function () {
        app()->make('router')->resetPassword();
    });
```

Note: the above code must be placed below `Auth::routes()` call

Answer (score 0):

add the following in Reset Controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

Comment: I added it to App/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController and not worked.